# C memcpy() Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have been getting Segmentation Fault again and again.
My purpose is to copy a File into a Shared Memory so that another Reader Process can read it.
To copy File, I have allocated M size Data Array in a Struct.
I have used NumberOfBuffers(N) and BufferSize(B) so that M=N*B.
The M is half of the file. So File Size is approximately 2M.
I think in this code memcpy() is generating the Segmentation Fault.
Initially my target is to full M size in Shared Memory through this Writer.c to see Copy at least is working.
My Operating System is Ubuntu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        char FileName[128];//POINTER PUTS DATA INTO NON-SHARED MEMORY
        int LastByteLength;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //THE FOLLOWING TYPECASTING AVOIDS THE NEED TO ATTACH THROUGH shmat() in shm.h HEADER I GUESS.
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        strcpy(M->FileName, "xaa");
        M->LastByteLength=0;
        M->ReadPointer=-1;
        M->WritePointer=-1;
        memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));
    }
    char FileName[128]="xaa";
    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        struct stat StatBuf;
        if(stat(FileName, &StatBuf)==-1){
            printf("failed to fstat %s\n", FileName);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        long long FileSize=StatBuf.st_size;
        printf("\n File Size: %lld", FileSize);
        long long FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        long long CopyableMemorySize=FileSize-FilePosition;
        printf("\n Copyable File Size: %lld", CopyableMemorySize);
        int NumberOfFileBuffers=CopyableMemorySize/BufferSize;
        printf("\n Number Of File Buffers: %d", NumberOfFileBuffers);
        for(int i=0; i<NumberOfFileBuffers; i++){
            if(abs(M->WritePointer-M->ReadPointer)==NumberOfBuffers){
                //WAIT
            }else{
                fseek(FP, i*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
                fread(Buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
                memcpy(&M->Data[i*BufferSize], Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));
           }
        }
        fclose(FP);
    }
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int BufferSize=51200; unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];` move from VLA to `malloc` to better handle out of stack case. As to `memcpy(&M->Data[i*BufferSize], Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));` why don't you simply check `if (i*BufferSize*sizeof(Buf) >= 512000) { error() }`? You have some printf in your code `printf("\n Number Of File Buffers: %d", NumberOfFileBuffers);` - so what do they print? What is the value of `NumberOfFileBuffers`? `FilePosition`? `CopyableMemorySize`? `sizeof(Buf)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Checking now.

Comment: `&M->Data[i*BufferSize]` will access outside the `Data` array when `i` is not `0`.

Comment: This seems peculiar: `memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));` where was a string written there? Better to use the buffer size, or if it is nulling a string, just set the first element to `'\0'`.

Comment: @protik internal to algorihthms out of memory accesses can be checked with assertions, ie. I would for sure write `assert(i * BufferSize * sizeof(Buf) < sizeof(M->Data));`

Comment: have you tried running valgrind on it?

Comment: @KamilCuk why is this 'i' being multiplied? I have put &M->Data[i*BufferSize] as an offset in the struct.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso No.

Comment: @KamilCuk, OK, checking.

Comment: @protik I am sorry, you are right, it should be `+` not `*` there. `i * BufferSize + sizeof(Buf)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk for expression i**BufferSize*sizeof(Buf)File Size: 1047714
 Copyable File Size: 1047714
 Number Of File Buffers: 20
 Checking: 0
 Checking: 2621440000
 Checking: 5242880000
 Checking: 7864320000
 Checking: 10485760000
 Checking: 13107200000
 Checking: 15728640000
 Checking: 18350080000
 Checking: 20971520000
 Checking: 23592960000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @protik you should try running some debugging tools on it, the answer will probably come up pretty easily.

Comment: @KamilCuk Checking this expression  printf("\n Checking: %d", i**BufferSize); fixed the problem. You are amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the file size is larger than the NumberOfBuffers, then this code requires a Mod Division not to access data outside M->Data array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void){
    struct MemData{
        char FileName[128];//POINTER PUTS DATA INTO NON-SHARED MEMORY
        int LastByteLength;
        int ReadPointer;
        int WritePointer;
        char Data[512000];//MEMORY BLOCK SIZE: 500 KB
    };
    int SD;
    struct MemData *M;
    int NumberOfBuffers=10;
    int BufferSize=51200;//FILE BUFFER SIZE 50 KB
    unsigned char Buf[BufferSize];

    SD= shm_open("/program.shared", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
    if(SD< 0){
        printf("\nshm_open() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fchmod(SD, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if(ftruncate(SD, sizeof(MemData))< 0){
        printf ("ftruncate() error \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //THE FOLLOWING TYPECASTING AVOIDS THE NEED TO ATTACH THROUGH shmat() in shm.h HEADER I GUESS.
    M=(struct MemData*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MemData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, SD, 0);
    if(M== MAP_FAILED){
        printf("mmap() error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        strcpy(M->FileName, "xaa");
        M->LastByteLength=0;
        M->ReadPointer=-1;
        M->WritePointer=-1;
        memset(M->Data, '\0', strlen(M->Data));
    }
    char FileName[128]="xaa";
    FILE *FP= fopen(FileName, "rb");
    if(FP!= NULL){
        struct stat StatBuf;
        if(stat(FileName, &StatBuf)==-1){
            printf("failed to fstat %s\n", FileName);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        long long FileSize=StatBuf.st_size;
        printf("\n File Size: %lld", FileSize);
        long long FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        FilePosition=ftell(FP);
        long long CopyableMemorySize=FileSize-FilePosition;
        printf("\n Copyable File Size: %lld", CopyableMemorySize);
        int NumberOfFileBuffers=CopyableMemorySize/BufferSize;
        printf("\n Number Of File Buffers: %d", NumberOfFileBuffers);
        for(int i=0; i<NumberOfFileBuffers; i++){
            int BufferModCount=i%NumberOfBuffers;
            if(abs(M->WritePointer-M->ReadPointer)==NumberOfBuffers){
                //WAIT
            }else{
                fseek(FP, i*BufferSize, SEEK_SET);
                fread(Buf, sizeof(unsigned char), BufferSize, FP);
                printf("\n Checking: %d", i*BufferSize);

                memcpy(&M->Data[BufferModCount*BufferSize], &Buf, sizeof(Buf)*sizeof(unsigned char));
            }
        }
        fclose(FP);
    }
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```